# How to load CSV data into a MySQL database when the raw data being loaded has many unique characters

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, database-design, import

In addition to that, I have to make sure that duplicate tickets are ignored from the new upload when the previous value in the database = `'closed', 'completed', 'cancelled', 'rejected'`.

Using Programs : **MS Excel 2013, MySQL 6.1 workbench 6.1.7**

The column names in **MySQL**:

```
Column Name Datatype    pk  nn  UQ  BIN UN  ZF  AI  Default
id          varchar(45)  Y  Y   Y                   
priority    tinytext                                Null
submit_dt   datetime                                Null
group       varchar(100)                            Null
comp_dt     datetime                                Null
status      varchar(45)                             Null
```

Raw sample in CSV:

```
id  priority    submit_dt       group     status    comp_dt
222 High        1/26/2015 7:08  bread     Closed    1/26/2015 15:23
333 High        1/26/2015 6:59  drinks    Closed    1/26/2015 13:36
444 High        1/20/2015 9:09  meat      Completed 1/20/2015 12:32
555 High        1/13/2015 10:27 salad     Closed    1/13/2015 12:53
777 High        1/12/2015 11:34 milk      Completed 1/13/2015 8:46
888 High        1/9/2015 10:29  crackers  Completed 1/9/2015 13:01
999 High        1/16/2015 14:59 soup      Closed    1/19/2015 12:26
100 High        1/6/2015 9:05   spices    Closed    1/6/2015 19:11
```

Comment: my apologies Drew.  Updating now

Answer (score 0):

MySQL database do not mind accepting unique characters.  Are you talking about non-Ascii characters?  I think you should make your question about duplicate tickets a separate question, and flesh it out a bit, with an example of what you'd like the database to store.

Comment: basically I have certain fields that use commas to separate things..  when I change it to comma separated, it does not separate how I want it to.  For instance, one of the fields will have xxx,xxx and when comma separated, it will break them up opposed to keeping it together as one column.  I agree to break this up into two questions, but it's important to know my planned method of import.  Sorry for the confusion and thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the "previous value" lines, I would recommend to write a VBA macro in Excel which goes through each line

`row = 2

do until cells(row,5)=""   ' 5 would be the relevant column-no.

   ...

   row=row+1

loop`

and check in the loop the relevant cell for previous values and erase these lines

```
if cell(row, 5)="completed" then
   range(cells(row,1),cells(row,10)).select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   row=row-1 
endif
```

then save the excel file as csv also through a macro command:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "path\filename.csv",
 FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True_
  'Local:= depends on the regional settings of your windows.
  `e.g. if your reg.set. are western europe and you select
   local:=true then the separation sign will be ";"`
```

In any case you should be able to change in excel and/or the macro the separation sign of csv-files

For a more professionell solution, I would recommend to write a C# application as a frontend for your data-exchange with a mySQL-DB. You could e.g. use the csv-reader solution from here 
(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), which would take care automatically of the separation sign problem. An object of this class loads the whole data as an array of lines in the memory and you could afterwards loop through the array to filter out the unwanted lines. Finally, you could create a parametrized SQL-string and using objects of the ADO.NET-class to load the data into the mySQL-db...